# Cannot create aws lambda function. error: the following arguments are required: --runtime, --handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, amazon-lambda

I am trying to deploy an image to be run in `aws lambda` at a scheduled interval. I have built and tested the image using [RIE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html) and locally it runs as it should. Next I have pushed the image to `aws ecr` to be stored. My next step is to create a `aws lambda function` and this is where my troubles begin. As per the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html):

> If the deployment package is a container image , then you set the package type to Image . For a container image, the code property must include the URI of a container image in the Amazon ECR registry. You do not need to specify the handler and runtime properties.

And when I try to create my lambda function which is:

```
aws lambda create-function --region <REGION> --function-name tft-image-test \
    --package-type Image  \
    --code ImageUri=<ACCOUNT-ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<REPOSITORY-NAME>:test-image   \
    --role <VALID-ROLE>
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: --runtime, --handler
```

The exact properties that I was not needed to specify are throwing me an error.

This is my first time using `aws` services, any help towards resolving this issue is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

awscli version: 1.18.69

Comment: What CLI version are you using?

Comment: @palvarez I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of containers with Lambda was introduced in CLI version >=2.2.0. You need to update your CLI version in order to make it work.